# Producing WSRP 1.0/2.0 from a standalone webapp - state of the art

Tags: java, producer, wsrp

I intend to produce WSRP interfaces from a standalone Java web application so that one can embed its front-end in portals (Liferay, IBM websphere portal), aside standalone front-end and back-ends.

What is the recommended way to achieve this ? I cannot find out a WSRP producer Java library that seems to do the job. The common practice of WSRP seems to link portals between them, as they natively support WSRP providers, consumers, and portlets specification.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: By the way, IBM provides a very simple PHP WSRP 2.0 producer there https://greenhouse.lotus.com/plugins/plugincatalog.nsf/assetDetails.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=EF06AE0641CC8567852576AB006ED5B8

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [OpenPortal Portlet Container](http://portlet-container.java.net/) to do this.